# Extract certain text from each line of text file using UNIX or perl

Tags: linux, unix, text-processing

I have a text file with lines like this:

```
Sequences (1:4) Aligned. Score:  4
Sequences (100:3011) Aligned. Score: 77
Sequences (12:345) Aligned. Score: 100
...
```

I want to be able to extract the values into a new tab delimited text file:

```
1 4 4
100 3011 77
12 345 100
```

(like this but with tabs instead of spaces)

Can anyone suggest anything? Some combination of sed or cut maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Perl:

```
cat data.txt | perl -pe 's/.*?(\d+):(\d+).*?(\d+)/$1\t$2\t$3/'
```

Or, to save to file:

```
cat data.txt | perl -pe 's/.*?(\d+):(\d+).*?(\d+)/$1\t$2\t$3/' > data2.txt
```

---

**Little explanation:**

Regex here is in the form:

```
s/RULES_HOW_TO_MATCH/HOW_TO_REPLACE/
```

How to match = .*?(\d+):(\d+).*?(\d+)

How to replace = $1\t$2\t$3

In our case, we used the following tokens to declare how we want to match the string:

- .*? - match any character ('.') as many times as possible ('*') as long as this character is not matching the next token in regex (which is \d in our case).
- \d+:\d+ - match at least one digit followed by colon and another number
- .*? - same as above
- \d+ - match at least one digit

Additionally, if some token in regex is in parentheses, it means "save it so I can reference it later". First parenthese will be known as '$1', second as '$2' etc. In our case:

```
.*?(\d+):(\d+).*?(\d+)
     $1    $2      $3
```

Finally, we're taking $1, $2, $3 and printing them out separated by tab (\t):

```
$1\t$2\t$3
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you - if you have a minute would you mind breaking it down so I can see how it works? Thanks again!

Comment: @squiguy, true, but I like it this way - it keeps my cursor closer to the regex which I tend to correct often, so it helps me save a second a day ;)

Comment: @AmyEllison, sure, I've added explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @kamituel That is really helpful. But I notice the output is not tab separated. It would be no big deal to do in text editor/spreadsheet program but my actual file is over 100 million lines long so can't open in excel/libre office etc. Can you adjust your perl code? thanks!

Comment: @AmyEllison - just use \t instead of space. \t is a symbol for tab. I'll update the code in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)/\1\t/g' infile
```

Here's a BSD sed compatible version:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)/\1'$'\t''/g' infile
```

The above solutions leave a trailing tab in the output, append `s/\t$//` or `s/'$'\t''$//` respectively to remove it.

If you know there will always be 3 numbers per line, you could go with grep:

```
<infile grep -o '[0-9]\+' | paste - - -
```

Output in all cases:

```
1       4       4       
100     3011    77      
12      345     100
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]\)*/\1     \2      \3/g' file.txt
```